# How to structure an asynchronous call to an API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I'm trying to write some code that makes a call to an API, which will then return some URLs, from each of which I'll then need to make a new call. To avoid nesting loads of callbacks everywhere I've tried using async/await, but it doesn't seem to be working for some reason despite the extremely simple setup I've tried.

I've tried to create two async functions, one of which makes the call to any url and returns the response, and another one which will then call the first function several times depending on the response (i.e. how many urls are returned).

```
const request = require('request');
init();

async function init() {
  const username = "x";
  const archiveUrl = "https://someurl.com";
  const archiveResponse = await apiCall(archiveUrl)
  const archives = archiveResponse.archives;
  console.log(archives);
}

async function apiCall(url) {
  request(url, { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
    if (err) { return console.log(err); }
    console.log(body);
    return body;
  });
}
```

This is literally my entire code at the moment and I'm not sure where it's going wrong. The error I'm getting is that it can't read .archives from undefined, and after that error message it's then logging the body from the apiCall function (making me fairly sure that the function isn't awaiting as expected).

That said I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Any tips on general best practice would be much appreciated, I've used async/await before but it's always been hacky and self-taught so I'm sure there's a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `apiCall` function you are using `callback` instead of `Promise`,  You need to promisify that function so that `const archiveResponse = await apiCall(archiveUrl)` actually works:

```
function apiCall(url) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    request(url, { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
      if (err) { return rej(err)}
      console.log(body);
      return res(body);
    });
  })
}
```

If you are using `async-await` please handle errors by enclosing this in `try..catch`

**Note:** Or you can use `request-promis` or `axios` they support promise out of the box.

Comment: Thanks! Stupid mistake, still getting used to having to constantly return promises everywhere...

Answer (score 0):

You are close!

```
let response = await fetch('https://someurl.com');
let data = await response.json(); 
console.log(response);
```

decode the JSON body of the response with `.json()` and it should work

Comment: What API has `fetch()`?  Or an async `json()` method for that matter?